# Image does not display

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm new in Ionic Angular and Typescript. I'm creating an app where user can upload their image in the app. I've manage to open the user library for him to choose the picture he wants to upload and the user can also take directly a picture with his device. I've tested the two functions (openLibrary and Camera ) and it works. But the only problem is that the picture do not display on my html file.
How can I resolve it ?

here is my typescript code :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { Camera, CameraOptions } from '@ionic-native/camera/ngx';
import { LoadingController, AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AngularFireStorage } from '@angular/fire/compat/storage';





@Component({
  selector: 'app-rajouter-produit',
  templateUrl: './rajouter-produit.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./rajouter-produit.page.scss'],
})
export class RajouterProduitPage implements OnInit {
  image = 'https://www.kasterencultuur.nl/editor/placeholder.jpg';
  imagePath: string;
  upload: any;
  imgURL: string;


  constructor(
    public loadingController: LoadingController,
    public alertController: AlertController,
    public afSG: AngularFirestore,
    public storageModule: AngularFireStorage,
    private camera: Camera,
    ) { }



uploadImage(filePath: string,file: any  ){
  return this.storageModule.upload(filePath, file).then((res) => {
  res.ref.getDownloadURL();
  });
}

imageName() {
const newTime = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
return Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + newTime;
}



async addPhoto(source: string){
  if(source === 'library'){
    console.log('library');
    await this.openLibrary().then(
    async (photo) => {
const imgData = await fetch(photo.webPath);
const blob = await imgData.blob();
const filePath = `events/thumbnails/${this.imageName()}`;
this.imgURL = await this.uploadImage(filePath, blob);

    },
    (err) => {console.log(err);}
    );


  }else{
    console.log('camera');
    await this.openCamera().then(
      async (photo) => {
  const imgData = await fetch(photo.webPath);
  const blob = await imgData.blob();
  const filePath = `events/thumbnails/${this.imageName()}`;
  this.imgURL = await this.uploadImage(filePath, blob);

      },
      (err) => {console.log(err);}
      );

  }
//const url =


}
async openCamera() {
  const options: CameraOptions = {
    quality: 100,
    destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
    targetWidth: 1000,
    targetHeight: 1000,
    sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA
  };
  return await this.camera.getPicture(options);
}

async openLibrary() {
  const options: CameraOptions = {
    quality: 100,
    destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
    encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
    targetWidth: 1000,
    targetHeight: 1000,
    sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
  };
  return await this.camera.getPicture(options);
}

  /*async adProduct(details: any){
  details.imgURL = this.imgURL;
  return this.afSG.collection('BTP').add(details);
  const loading = await this.loadingController.create();
  await loading.present();
  await loading.dismiss();
const alert= await this.alertController.create({
header:'Félicitation',
message: 'C\'est envoyé !',
buttons: ['OK']
});
}*/

  async adProduct(details: any){
  details.imgURL = this.imgURL;
  const loading = await this.loadingController.create();
  await loading.present();

 this.imagePath = new Date().getTime() + 'data:image/jpeg;base64,';
 this.afSG.collection ('BTP').add(details);
 this.upload.then(async () => {
await loading.dismiss();
const alert= await this.alertController.create({
header:'Félicitation',
message: 'C\'est envoyé !',
buttons: ['OK']
});

 });

}




  ngOnInit() {

  }




}
```

and my HTML code :

```
 <ion-list>
      <ion-item lines="none">
        <ion-button expand="block" color = "warning" (click)="addPhoto('library')">
          <ion-icon slot="start" name="image"></ion-icon>Parcourir</ion-button>
          <ion-button expand="block" color = "secondary" (click)="addPhoto('camera')">
            <ion-icon slot="start" name="camera"></ion-icon>Camera</ion-button>
      </ion-item>

        <ion-card>
          <div class="flex">
            <div class="img-box">
              <img [src]="image" >
            </div>
          </div>
        </ion-card>
```

Thank you !

I'm trying to display the image taken by the user on my html file. The result I get is a broken picture and when I go to storage in firebase the image Url leads me to a blank page.

Answer (score -1):

You need to check how the image was uploaded to the server and then convert it back. check out the ionic docs how to do that, they also provide example how to do this.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/your-first-app/taking-photos

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped me, I manage to display the image. But the image URL in Firebase Storage leads me to a page "Cannot Get / undefined".

Comment: What does the URL look like?

Comment: it looks like this : https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/kira-2-e7e6b.appspot.com/o/events%2Fthumbnails%2F1670320495?alt=media&token=aa6eaf87-a831-4d2c-9cfc-2969614347c2

Comment: you need to convert it to be viewable

Comment: How do you do that please ?